# Cucumber Report Plugin showing base64 encoded image as broken link

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, watir

I've an automation suite using Ruby-Cucumber-Watir and I'm trying to execute it from Jenkins on a windows server. Everything is working fine except that the screenshots encoded as base64 are appearing as broken links in Jenkins Cucumber Report.

Cucumber reports plugin - 4.9.0

ruby - 2.6.0p0

Cucumber - 3.1.2

Watir - 6.16.5

Screenshot are displayed correctly when I embed them as a PNG file instead of base64 encoded image.

Below is the code to capture screenshot:

```rb
image = @browser.driver.screenshot_as(:base64)
embed("data:image/png;base64,#{image}", 'image/png')
```

And I've below in my cucumber.yml file to generate JSON file for cucumber-report plugin:

```
-f pretty -f json -o results/temp/JSON/results.json
```

[image: This is how it appears]
And it works fine when I save the file and then embed it as below:

```rb
@browser.screenshot.save 'screenshot.png'
embed 'screenshot.png', 'image/png'
```

Please not that the code using Base64 works fine when I run it locally. All images are displayed properly in the HTML Report built using `report_builder` gem.

Comment: I'm wondering if the `embed` method call is to blame. It might need to be `embed(image, 'image/png')`. I bet it will add the `data:image` and mime type for you automatically."

Comment: @GregBurghardt You're right, I don't need to add `data:image` but still it didn't help. Also, this code work flawlessly when I run it locally.

Comment: I would check where the images are getting saved and check what is the broken link looks like ( view page source)

Comment: you may need to modify the jenkins job to save out the screenshot artifacts at the end of the run.

Comment: @Sureshmani when I try to access the .png file in embeddings folder, I get an alert `Paint cannot read this file. This is not a valid bitmap file, or it's format is not currently supported`

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden those artifacts are there but unable to view them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your code should be as follows:

```
image = @browser.driver.screenshot_as(:base64)
embed(image, 'image/png;base64')
```

Some other examples:

```
Given("you have attached 3 files") do
  require 'base64'
  an_image_in_text = 'features/upload-files/base64image.txt'
  content = File.read(an_image_in_text)
  embed(content, 'image/png;base64')

  content02 = File.read('my_html_file.html')
  embed(content02, 'text/html;base64')

  image = File.open('my_image.png', 'rb') do |img|
      Base64.strict_encode64(img.read)
    end
  embed(image, 'image/png;base64')
end
```

[More about mime types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types)

Hope it helps!